# jsp look alike syntax in android does it exist?

Tags: android, jsp

is there a syntax to work dynamical in android xml files ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing like JSP built into Android. You may be able to use smaller third-party template libraries, like StringTemplate.